# Can I glue stucco back onto a block wall?

Tags: walls

Can I re-glue it back to the cement wall? I am thinking that I can squirt some bonding agent between the loose stucco and the block wall.

Comment: Including a couple of pics might help, but it's probably _far_ more important to figure out _why_ the original bond is failing. This might work as a short term fix, but the root cause will probably cause more to fail, and will likely cause your short term fix to fail too.